# What does the acronym CFNM stand for in sexuality?

Tags: american-english, terminology

I have heard the term "CFNM" being used in sexuality, does anybody know what the term means ?

(Note: OP said "CNFM", but another user edited that to "CFNM".)

Actually 'googling' didn't help at all. While I was either getting 'scientific terms' or link to porn videos but none were sharing the term. I even tried 'define:cfnm' but even that bit didn't help, usually it does.

Comment: Isn't an acronym supposed to be pronounceable as a word? So *cfnm* is just an abbreviation, not an acronym, right?

Comment: @Joffysloffy technically speaking it's an initialism, but abbreviation is also fine. And -1 from me because I found the answer in less than 5 minutes by Googling

Comment: @Mari-LouA I knew there was something more specific than *abbreviation*… Thank you!

Comment: There are a number of sites which reference "CNFM", if you can convince Google to search for them.  (Hint, put quotes around the letters.)  A bunch are porn and appear to really be referring to "CFNM" (though they contain "CNFM" in their text), but a bunch are "legit", such as the "Center for Nanohybrid Functional Materials".

Comment: WOW! Center for Nanohybrid Functional Materials--tres sexy

Comment: @Cascabel - Whatever turns you on!

Comment: Actually 'googling' didn't help at all. While I was either getting 'scientific terms' or link to porn videos but none were sharing the term. I even tried 'define:cfnm' but even that bit didn't help, usually it does.

Comment: @shirish Are you perhaps just having a laugh here by sending unsuspecting ELU participants in direction of porn :-) ?

Comment: But you knew it was about sexual content, it's in your question. And that's how I understood when I found  the answer. Just Google CFNM, there's even a wikipedia page on the first page of results

Comment: I could have sworn that a _cnfm_ was a Welsh term for a cleft crag.

Comment: I believe it stands for Cis (someone who identifies with the opposite of their biological state, if I understand correctly) Female, Neutrois (essentially gender neutral  if i understand correctly .. http://neutrois.com/ ) or Male.  I'm sure CFNM isn't 'inclusive' enough to satisfy everyone and I can't provide any guidance on how many people you'd offend or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [UrbanDictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=CFNM):

> Clothed Female Naked Male - A sexual scenario that the male(s) is naked and the female(s) is fully clothed.

It seems imply some sort of role reversal and have a negative connotation in the pornographic industry.

Comment: The question does say cnfm. Twice.

Comment: @DJClayworth I believe this to be an error on the OP part, and have edited the question as  all results for "cnfm" redirect to "cfnm". I am incorrect the OP can roll back and I will delete my answer.

Comment: I must be a very innocent old man. I have discovered, for the first time, two entries, that I had never heard of, from the glossary of sexual practices, in two days -  Golden Showers, and now CFNM? Whatever next?

Comment: @WS2 You. Don't. Want. To. Know.